# Why does not WiringPiISR block the main routine when it is fired?

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, embedded, wiringpi

I am developing a program in C to run on a raspberry board. In the program i want to use WiringPiISR to handle a pin triggered interrupt. However, I have found that instead of blocking the main routine, the wiringPiISR creates a concurrent thread. Am i missing something?

Minimal code example :

```
#include <WiringPi.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int Check=0;
void Isr()
{
    while (1)
    {
       sleep(1);
       Check++;
    }
}

int main()
{
     wiringPiSetup () ;
     pinMode(7, INPUT) ;
     wiringPiISR (7, INT_EDGE_BOTH ,&Isr);
     while (1)
      {
         sleep(2);
         printf("check : %d", Check );
      }
   return 0;
}
```

I would expect this minimal program to never resume after the interrupt is fired but in my case it kept on incrementing the variable check and printing it on the screen ( both threads working concurrently).

Comment: Do not call sleep() in an ISR!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](http://wiringpi.com/reference/priority-interrupts-and-threads/) I've found is rather specific (emphasis mine):

> int wiringPiISR (int pin, int edgeType,  void (*function)(void)) ;
>
> This function is run at a high priority (if the program is run using sudo, or as root) and **executes concurrently** with the main program. It has full access to all the global variables, open file handles and so on.

The [sources](https://github.com/UplinkCoder/wiringpi/blob/master/wiringPiISR.c#L106) don't leave anything to imagination. It just crates a new thread:

```
pthread_create (&threadId, NULL, interruptHandler, &pin) ;
```

that waits for interrupt and executes your handler:

```
static void *interruptHandler (void *arg)
{
  int pin = *(int *)arg ;

  (void)piHiPri (55) ;

  for (;;)
  {
    if (waitForInterrupt (pin, -1) > 0)
      isrFunctions [pin] () ;
  }

  return NULL ;
}
```

So your handler runs as a separate thread and your behavior is expected.

Answer (score 0):

*ISR* stands for *interrupt service routine* aka interrupt handler.

Your code sets up an interrupt handler. If the interrupt is fired, the regular code (`main()` in your case) is interrupted and the interrupt handler is executed. It's not a second thread but the result is similar.

Interrupt handlers should only do minimal work and quickly return control to the interrupted program. The use of `sleep()` in an interrupt handler is not allowed and causes undefined behavior.

Comment: I would say the while(1){} in the IRQ is even worse.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you've made the infinite loop and the call of `sleep()` on purpose:

`sleep()` probably allows to switch between the threads.

Comment: this was just a minimal example to stress the point but i guess the use of sleep() was good as it revealed other pieces information.