# How to implement a real ISR using arm interrupts in Raspberry pi?

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, arm, interrupt

I am building an application in C to be deployed to a Raspberry pi 3 board, in which,I will be using a gpio driven interrupt.
I have tried with "WiringPiISR()" but i found that it does not really create an ISR handler as pointed out in the question:
[Why does not WiringPiISR block the main routine when it is fired?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57315755/why-does-not-wiringpiisr-block-the-main-routine-when-it-is-fired).
 What i need is a way to use arm interrupts in C and not just a workaround!!

Comment: You've got an operating system in between there. You cannot do any interrupt handlers. To do interrupt handlers you need to either modify the operating system kernel **or** write your **own operating system kernel**.

Comment: It is wrong that you need an OS. However the machinery is quite complex.  There is a layering of interrupt “controllers” each with enable/pending flags.  There are at least three layer, an interrupt stack, cp15 registers and the irq assembler.  Approx 2-10k of more obscure machine code.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it's impossible! At least until you are using an Operating System in non-kernel mode. Although you can write a driver (Kernel Module in Linux) for your OS ([The Linux Kernel Module Programming Guide](https://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/Linux_Kernel_Module_Programming_Guide/x1236.html)), Or ignore the OS and develop your own program in bare-metal mode (It needs a high-level knowledge).